# Pandas: Retain the a particular row based on weightage given on a particular column, if duplicates are present based on other columns after groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a data frame **df**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["A","X",98,56,61], ["B","E",79,54,36], ["A","Y",98,56,61],["B","F",79,54,36], ["A","Z",98,56,61], ["A","W",48,51,85],["B","G",44,57,86],["B","H",79,54,36]], columns=["id","class","c1","c2","c3"])
```

when we do groupby on **id**, if duplicate values(rows) are present based on multiple columns like **c1,c2,c3**, retain the row based on weighatge given on column **class**.

For example here when we do groupby on **id** A, **c1,c2,c3** are duplicates for class **X,Y,Z**, among X,Y,Z weighatge given to **X** so retain **X** and delete other rows, similarly among **E,F,H** weightage given to **F**, so retain **F** and delete other rows.

**Expected Output:**

```
output = pd.DataFrame([["A","X",98,56,61],["B","F",79,54,36],["A","W",48,51,85],["B","G",44,57,86]], columns=["id","class","c1","c2","c3"])
```

How to do it?

Comment: Use `df = df.drop_duplicates(['id','c1','c2','c3'])`

Comment: its not clear why you want to retain `F` instead of `E` for id `B` for example, is there any specific weightage? can you please clarify

Comment: yes there is specific weightage, if X,Y,Z are duplicates, retain X row, if E,F,H are duplicates then retain F row

Comment: In that case., I do not think this is a duplicate question. reopened. But you should try to explain the question a bit more as it is slight confusing to read

Comment: duplicate is on c1,c2 and c3

Comment: @Chethan Are you defining the weightage based on the given `id` so lets say for id `A` you want to keep only the duplicate rows where class is `X`, similarly for id `B` you want to keep duplicated rows where the corresponding class is `F`?

Comment: no weightage only based on class column, if x,y,z then chose x row if the duplicate rows are present, if e,f,h then chose f row id duplicate is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your explanation, you can create a dictionary of the weightage and then create 2 conditions and then do:

```
#add classes for weightage incase of duplicates
cls = ['X','F']
c = df.duplicated(['id','c1','c2','c3'],keep=False) 
out = df[(c&df['class'].isin(cls))|~c]
```

---

```
print(out)

  id class  c1  c2  c3
0  A     X  98  56  61
3  B     F  79  54  36
5  A     W  48  51  85
6  B     G  44  57  86
```

Comment: here u have given weightage based on id column, for giving weightage i am not using id column, it is purely on class column, like if duplicate row is present of x,y,z chose x row, if duplicate row is present in e,f,h choose f row like this

Comment: @Chethan updated answer to accommodate that requirement.